# XML to pandas: Export to csv and make the childrens in same row

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am in the "munging stage", trying to convert a XML file to csv with pandas. I finally did with the code bellow:

```
for element in etree.iterparse(path):     
    data.append({element.tag: element.text})
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['NOME_DISTRITO', 'NR_CPE', 'MARCA_EQUIPAMENTO',
                                'NR_EQUIPAMENTO','VALOR_LEITURA','REGISTADOR',
                                'TIPO_REGISTADOR','TIPO_DADOS_RECOLHIDOS','FACTOR_MULTIPLICATIVO_FINAL',
                                'NR_DIGITOS_INTEIRO','UNIDADE_MEDIDA','TIPO_LEITURA','MOTIVO_LEITURA',
                                'ESTADO_LEITURA','DATA_LEITURA','HORA_LEITURA'])

df.to_csv('/lecture.csv')
```

This is the XML file:

```html
<DISTRITO xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NOME_DISTRITO>BRAGANCA</NOME_DISTRITO>

  <CPE>
    <NR_CPE>PT000200003724</NR_CPE>

    <LEITURA>
      <MARCA_EQUIPAMENTO>102</MARCA_EQUIPAMENTO>
      <NR_EQUIPAMENTO>30806746</NR_EQUIPAMENTO>
      <VALOR_LEITURA>16858</VALOR_LEITURA>
      <REGISTADOR>001</REGISTADOR>
      <TIPO_REGISTADOR>S</TIPO_REGISTADOR>
      <TIPO_DADOS_RECOLHIDOS>1</TIPO_DADOS_RECOLHIDOS>
      <FACTOR_MULTIPLICATIVO_FINAL>1</FACTOR_MULTIPLICATIVO_FINAL>
      <NR_DIGITOS_INTEIRO>5</NR_DIGITOS_INTEIRO>
      <UNIDADE_MEDIDA>kWh</UNIDADE_MEDIDA>
      <TIPO_LEITURA>2</TIPO_LEITURA>
      <MOTIVO_LEITURA>2</MOTIVO_LEITURA>
      <ESTADO_LEITURA>A</ESTADO_LEITURA>
      <DATA_LEITURA>20151218</DATA_LEITURA>
      <HORA_LEITURA>083800</HORA_LEITURA>
    </LEITURA>
    <LEITURA>
      <MARCA_EQUIPAMENTO>102</MARCA_EQUIPAMENTO>
      <NR_EQUIPAMENTO>30806746</NR_EQUIPAMENTO>
      <VALOR_LEITURA>16925</VALOR_LEITURA>
      <REGISTADOR>001</REGISTADOR>
      <TIPO_REGISTADOR>S</TIPO_REGISTADOR>
      <TIPO_DADOS_RECOLHIDOS>1</TIPO_DADOS_RECOLHIDOS>
      <FACTOR_MULTIPLICATIVO_FINAL>1</FACTOR_MULTIPLICATIVO_FINAL>
      <NR_DIGITOS_INTEIRO>5</NR_DIGITOS_INTEIRO>
      <UNIDADE_MEDIDA>kWh</UNIDADE_MEDIDA>
      <TIPO_LEITURA>1</TIPO_LEITURA>
      <MOTIVO_LEITURA>1</MOTIVO_LEITURA>
      <ESTADO_LEITURA>A</ESTADO_LEITURA>
      <DATA_LEITURA>20160119</DATA_LEITURA>
      <HORA_LEITURA>203000</HORA_LEITURA>
    </LEITURA>
   </CPE>
```

And this is the final result in Excel:

NOME_DISTRITO   NR_CPE  MARCA_EQUIPAMENTO   NR_EQUIPAMENTO  VALOR_LEITURA   REGISTADOR  TIPO_REGISTADOR TIPO_DADOS_RECOLHIDOS   FACTOR_MULTIPLICATIVO_FINAL NR_DIGITOS_INTEIRO  UNIDADE_MEDIDA  TIPO_LEITURA    MOTIVO_LEITURA  ESTADO_LEITURA  DATA_LEITURA    HORA_LEITURA
BRAGANCA

```
PT000200003724                          

    102                                                 
        30806746                                                
            16925                                           
                1                                       
                    S                                   
                        1                               
                            1                           
                                5                       
                                    kWh                 
                                        1               
                                            1           
                                                A       
                                                    20160119    
                                                        203000
```

All I want is to have this data in the same row after the column "MARCA_EQUIPAMENTO", but as you can see this is like a "shape staircase row". Is there anything that I can do with pandas or excel to fix and have in a nice manner in excel?

NOME_DISTRITO   NR_CPE  MARCA_EQUIPAMENTO   NR_EQUIPAMENTO  VALOR_LEITURA   REGISTADOR  TIPO_REGISTADOR TIPO_DADOS_RECOLHIDOS   FACTOR_MULTIPLICATIVO_FINAL NR_DIGITOS_INTEIRO  UNIDADE_MEDIDA  TIPO_LEITURA    MOTIVO_LEITURA  ESTADO_LEITURA  DATA_LEITURA    HORA_LEITURA
BRAGANCA
    PT0002000021673724JE
        102 30806746    16858   1   S   1   1   5   kWh 2   2   A   20151218    83800
        102 30806746    16925   1   S   1   1   5   kWh 1   1   A   20160119    203000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider running conditionals in the `iterparse()`. Because `<NOME_DISTRITO>` and `<NR_CPE>` lie outside the repeated `<LEITURA>` elements, save their values in scalars to be added to the `inner{}` dictionary for appending to dataframe:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import pandas as pd

path ='/path/to/Input.xml'

data = []
for (ev, el) in et.iterparse(path):
    if el.tag == 'NOME_DISTRITO': nome = el.text
    if el.tag == 'NR_CPE': nr = el.text
    if el.tag == "LEITURA":
        inner = {}
        inner['NOME_DISTRITO'] = nome
        inner['NR_CPE'] = nr
        for i in el:
            inner[i.tag] = i.text        
        data.append(inner)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

#   DATA_LEITURA ESTADO_LEITURA FACTOR_MULTIPLICATIVO_FINAL HORA_LEITURA  \
# 0     20151218              A                           1       083800   
# 1     20160119              A                           1       203000   

#   MARCA_EQUIPAMENTO MOTIVO_LEITURA NOME_DISTRITO          NR_CPE  \
# 0               102              2      BRAGANCA  PT000200003724   
# 1               102              1      BRAGANCA  PT000200003724   

#   NR_DIGITOS_INTEIRO NR_EQUIPAMENTO REGISTADOR TIPO_DADOS_RECOLHIDOS  \
# 0                  5       30806746        001                     1   
# 1                  5       30806746        001                     1   

#   TIPO_LEITURA TIPO_REGISTADOR UNIDADE_MEDIDA VALOR_LEITURA  
# 0            2               S            kWh         16858  
# 1            1               S            kWh         16925
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works a lot!. Everytime i have an element that is outside of another element it is necessary to do that?

Comment: There are many ways to parse XML. Since `iterparse()` does not manage relationships like `xpath()` but only reads line by line, you need to somehow capture static grandparent/parent values outside of changing element values.

Comment: So what do you recommend me for parsing a large XML file? With iterparse() it is working to me so far! Thanks for ur help @Parfait :)

Comment: In this case, `iterparse()` will work and especially for larger XML files, so continue on. I was just answering your earlier question about capturing outside elements. Glad I could help.